# How to run this batch file in Hidden mode

Tags: batch-file

Batch file content:

```
@echo off

timeout /T 60 >null

taskkill /F /IM wzqkpick.exe

wmic product where "name like '%%winzip%%'" call Uninstall

If Exist "%programfiles(x86)%\Winzip\winzip32.exe" GOTO 64

If Exist "%programfiles%\Winzip\winzip32.exe" "%programfiles%\WinZip\Winzip32.exe" /Uninstallx

taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe

GOTO :END

:64

"%programfiles(x86)%\WinZip\Winzip32.exe" /Uninstallx

taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe

:END
```

Comment: See [this SU link](http://superuser.com/questions/756630/running-windows-batch-file-without-popup)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with VBS.

I used something much simpler than in your example (did now want to do all uninstalls, taskkill). So `my.bat`:

```
If Exist "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" call "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Then created `hidden.vbs` file:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) & chr(34), 0, False
```

Then using a script hosting tool:

```
D:\myfolder>wscript.exe "hidden.vbs" "my.bat"
```

After doing that there's notepad.exe opening for me silently.
Note the `0` argument for `intWindowStyle` in `Run` method - it makes hiding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot this thing:

[Place the code after "@echo off"]

```
cmd /c powershell -Nop -NonI -Nologo -WindowStyle Hidden "Write-Host"
```